# Python: How to get a constant from the scope a class is in?

Tags: python, django

I want to use the value of a constant defined in django's settings.py inside a class.

I know I can `from myprojectname import settings` but I want to make it a python package so it'd be better if I could get those values from the scope the class is instantiated.

Passing it to every instance would be inconvenient since these constants would be used throughout an entire project.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can still do this way,`from django.conf import settings; settings.MEDIA_URL.`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. But that'd limit the package to django.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you want to have as few dependencies as possible.

Since I know no way to use variables from the context a class was instantiated in, I would prefer to do something like that:

```
class Independent(object):

  def __init__(self, context):
     self._context = context
```

Thus the instantiating code can provide a context object that can contain any context information you need to have for operation. This would make the class totally independent from the context -- but comes with a price of course, since you must provide the information at any instantiation. But you merely need only one such object for any context you have, so the memory overhead is limited to one additional property.

An other option would be, that the module has a global context variable. When you import the module, you can set the value as needed in one of your more specific modules, but you should do it in the modules coding of course. All the classes in the module can use this global variable. Of course, in any program you are limited than to one context for the whole module, but in different programs you can have different contexts and your module is not depending on some specifics like "Django".